# Open Source EDI Mapper

Tags: open-source

I don't find a good open source which has a nice mapper UI which supports ANSI, EDIFACT EDI messages.

Does anyone knows any good open source which supports cross platform and EDIFACT, ANSI?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please give an example of such a mapping?

Comment: EDI to XML or XML to EDI or EDI to any format conversion - csv, flat file, xml, dat file etc.,

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the end? A flat file containing all information from an EDI message is probably less usable and less readable than the original.

Comment: Trying to achieve what the end user will require. Translating to end user's ouput by merely configuration. Whenever there is a change instead of building the application again..Just trying to import/export the mapping configuration alone